# create phoenix table where primary key is in descending order

Tags: sql, hbase, apache-phoenix

I am trying to create table like:

```
`create table avtivity_manager(
  ActivityDateTime bigint not null primary key desc,
  UserID varchar,
  CreatedDateTime bigint desc,
  AvtivityType varchar,
  RunSpeed float,
  ActivityID varchar,
  );`
```

I am getting error

> Error: ERROR 604 (42P00): Syntax error. Mismatched input. Expecting
>   "RPAREN", got "desc" at line 4, column 26. (state=42P00,code=604)
>   org.apache.phoenix.exception.PhoenixParserException: ERROR 604
>   (42P00): Syntax error. Mismatched input. Expecting "RPAREN", got
>   "desc" at line 4, column 26.  at
>   org.apache.phoenix.exception.PhoenixParserException.newException(PhoenixParserException.java:33)
>     at
>   org.apache.phoenix.parse.SQLParser.parseStatement(SQLParser.java:111)
>     at
>   org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement$PhoenixStatementParser.parseStatement(PhoenixStatement.java:1280)
>     at
>   org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement.parseStatement(PhoenixStatement.java:1363)
>     at
>   org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement.execute(PhoenixStatement.java:1434)
>     at sqlline.Commands.execute(Commands.java:822)  at
>   sqlline.Commands.sql(Commands.java:732)   at
>   sqlline.SqlLine.dispatch(SqlLine.java:808)    at
>   sqlline.SqlLine.begin(SqlLine.java:681)   at
>   sqlline.SqlLine.start(SqlLine.java:398)   at
>   sqlline.SqlLine.main(SqlLine.java:292) Caused by:
>   MismatchedTokenException(41!=129)     at
>   org.apache.phoenix.parse.PhoenixSQLParser.recoverFromMismatchedToken(PhoenixSQLParser.java:360)
>     at
>   org.apache.phoenix.shaded.org.antlr.runtime.BaseRecognizer.match(BaseRecognizer.java:115)
>     at
>   org.apache.phoenix.parse.PhoenixSQLParser.create_table_node(PhoenixSQLParser.java:1126)
>     at
>   org.apache.phoenix.parse.PhoenixSQLParser.oneStatement(PhoenixSQLParser.java:816)
>     at
>   org.apache.phoenix.parse.PhoenixSQLParser.statement(PhoenixSQLParser.java:508)
>     at
>   org.apache.phoenix.parse.SQLParser.parseStatement(SQLParser.java:108)
>     ... 9 more

I think I am missing something but not able to figure out. Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Only a primary key can be marked](https://phoenix.apache.org/language/index.html#column_def) as `desc` or `asc`. `CreatedDateTime` is not a primary key, and so cannot be descending.